# Mono Droid MvxAdapter NotifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a MvxAdapter to view images in a MvxGridview. Everything works fine, until i remove an item from the ItemSource.

My view wont upgrade (the GetView()-Method is not called, after removing an item). But why?

I call following method, after the ItemsSource-Collection has changed (not depending on remove or adding items)

```
RunOnUiThread(() => _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());
```

The adapter is created as following:

```
// Create adapter
_adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);

// Get gridview and set adapter
var gridview = FindViewById<MvxGridView>(Resource.Id.uploadprogress_imagegrid);
gridview.Adapter = _adapter;
```

And here the GetView()-Method of the CustomAdapter

```
protected override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, int templateId)
    {
        var data = GetRawItem(position) as PhoneImageItem;
        if (data == null) return null;

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(templateId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder
            {
                Image = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.phonepictures_item),
                Foreground = convertView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.phonepictures_foreground)
            };

            convertView.Tag = holder;
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.Tag;
        }

        // Get bitmap from lru-cache
        var bmp = GetBitmapFromMemCache(data.Filepath);
        if (bmp == null)
        {
            LoadBitmap(data.Filepath, holder.Image);
        }
        else
        {
            // Set bitmap from cache
            holder.Image.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

        // Set selected-layout
        holder.Foreground.Visibility = (data.IsSelected) ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;

        return convertView;
    }
```

I dont know what to do. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a custom adapter, what is the reason? From what I can see is that you are using it for a custom view, but you can achieve exactly the same with bindings and an ItemTemplate.

Comment: No, I need the custom adapter for memory-reasons. I show up to 200 images in this view and without the adapter, an OOM-Exception occurd.

Comment: Could you please report the OOM exception to the GitHub issues with the stack trace and a reproducible, because that is not supposed to happen.

Comment: My 'LoadBitmap' method loads the bitmap from an api with a AsyncTask. This is the first reason, why i need the adatper.

And second: Is there a way to show an image from the internal-app-storage with a binding directly to the ImageView?